# PowerShell read csv column and adjacent cell line by line

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV with 2 columns.
Im having difficulty to copy the contents of a folder path in cell B2 and paste into path of B1
then go through each line of the csv document.

My CSV looks like this...

```
"OriginalName","NewName"

"C:\Share-Temp","\\\networkLoc\C_Share-Temp"
"C:\Users\Mtr54\AppData\Local\Greenshot","\\\networkLoc\C_Users_Mtr54_AppData_Local_Greenshot"
"C:\Users\Mtr54\AppData\Local\Audacity","\\\networkLoc\C_Users_Mtr54_AppData_Local_Audacity"
```

.

```
$csv = import-csv "\\networkLoc\csv.csv" | foreach {
$line in $csv Copy-Item -path $t2\$($_.NewName) -Destination $_.OriginalName -Recurse  -Force
}
```

But not having any luck..

Anybody got some pointers for my dilemma?

TIA

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your whacky foreach loop? Why not just do `import-csv "\\networkLoc\csv.csv"`

Comment: You are mixing the `foreach` command with `foreach-object`'s alias `foreach`. The `foreach` command has syntax `foreach ($line in $csv) { ... }`. There is no `$_` in `foreach` command because the current item is `$line` in this particular example.

Comment: AdminOfThings - You are spot on about the foreach-object.  That corrected the issue.  
Now I need to figure out how to copy just contents of folder to destination..

Comment: Using test-path and use of wildcard character I succeeded with this portion of script.  Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

Does your CSV have headers? Because you should be making the call with the header name

$csv = import-csv "\networkLoc\csv.csv"
foreach ($line in $csv){
Copy-Item -path $line.Header1$line.header2 -Destination $line.OriginalName -Recurse  -Force
}